# ~200ms Touch (Click) Delay in Cordova but not in Browser or PWA

Tags: html, cordova, webview, progressive-web-apps

I am currently converting my web app to a Cordova app. And I ran into a strange problem:

In Safari or when adding my app to the home screen, all touch inputs (Clicks/Touch) are fast (no delay) but when deploying my app as a Cordova project the inputs (Clicks/Touch) are slow (about 200-300ms delay - no measurement just an estimate based on the well-known touch delay problem).

I am testing on an iPhone Xs running iOS 12.3 and I am building the app with Cordova 9.0.0.

The following viewport settings are used by the app:

`<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the inputs are slow"? Do you mean typing in an input field? What are touch inputs? Click?

Comment: Yes, I meant clicks. Basically, it looks like the (Cordova) Webview waits for the double tap but the browser and the add-to-home-screen app doesn't.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I'm experiencing identical behavior and planning to add the ancient "fastclick" lib to sort it out - but that's disappointing, knowing that a tiny config change in the ios webview control can provide a native (vs JS-hack) solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace your 'click' events with 'touchstart' events. You can detect if you are in a webview by doing

```
  var click = 'click';

  if(typeof(window.ontouchstart) !== 'undefined'){
        click = 'touchstart';
  }
```

Then listen to you click event using the click variable. Using jQuery

```
  $('#something').on(click, function(event){...
```

Answer (score 0):

TESTED AT: **Chrome**

It happens because there is something that expands body, some elements are bigger than a device width. Sooo the solution will be to show browser that we don't need his help, you can handle it by yourself:

```
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Finally you got something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  html,
  body {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

But the browser still allows you to add scrolling to elements below **body**.
In other words, if your code doesn't interfere with html or body tag, it shouldn't inflict problems in your app.